# Visual Studio: How to trigger an alarm when a breakpoint is hit?

Tags: visual-studio, breakpoints

Is there a way to trigger a beep/alarm/sound when my breakpoint is hit? I'm using Visual Studio 2005/2008.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why you need this? I do not think such a "alarm"-feature exists, but if you provide us with your scenario on why you need this, we could maybe give you another solution.

Comment: I test my code on a PC in an adjacent cube and it takes a while before my debugging breakpoint is hit. So, while I'm at my own PC I would like to know when my breakpoint is hit. A short audible alarm or even a beep would be enough for this.

Comment: * need to restart visual studio for these settings to take effect (VS2010)
- and this is the same place you need to go to enable 'Successful' or 'Failed' build noises

Answer (score 97, accepted):

#### Windows XP

Control Panel -> Sounds and Audio... -> Program Events - Microsoft Developer -> Breakpoint Hit

#### Windows 7

Control Panel -> All Control Panel Items -> Sounds -> Sounds (tab) - Microsoft Visual Studio -> Breakpoint Hit

Comment: I used to have the "Build Failure" sound set to Tom Hanks' "Houston we have a problem". Yeah, stupid I know, but it was successful at annoying my coworkers. :)

Comment: And in Win 10 you find the setting like this:
Settings -> Personalization -> Themes -> Advanced Sound Settings -> Microsoft Visual Studio -> Breakpoint Hit

Comment: This is perfect.  I needed this for a long running process where the break point might get hit once every 10 minutes or so...  Nice to be able to do something else while this is going.

Comment: Still useful on Windows 2016, VS2015! Thanks!

Comment: For my Win 10, a little different: Settings -> Personalization -> Themes -> "Sounds" under Current theme -> Sounds tab -> Microsoft Visual Studio under Program Events: -> Breakpoint Hit

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can do it with a Macro assigned to a breakpoint.  This works in VS 2005, I assume 2008 will work as well.  I assume you don't want a sound on EVERY breakpoint, or the other answer will work fine.  There is probably a way to play a specific sound, but I didn't dig that hard.  Here are the basic steps:

**Add A New Macro Module** (steps below the code)

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Module Beeps
    Public Sub WindowsBeep()
        Interaction.Beep()
    End Sub
    Public Sub ForceBeep()
        Beep(900, 300)
    End Sub
    <DllImport("Kernel32.dll")> _
    Private Function Beep(ByVal frequency As UInt32, ByVal duration As UInt32) As Boolean
    End Function
End Module
```

1. Tools => Macros => Macros IDE
2. My Macros (In Project Explorer) => Add New Module => Name: "Beeps"
3. Copy the above code in.  It has 2 methods

   1. First one uses the windows "Beep" sound
   2. Second one forces a "Beep" tone, not a .wav file.  This works with all sounds disabled (eg Control Panel -> Sounds -> Sound Scheme: No Sounds), but sounds ugly.
4. View the Macro Explorer in VS.Net (not the macro IDE) to make sure it is there :)

**Assign To A Breakpoint**

1. Add a break point to a line
2. Right click on the little red dot
3. Select "When Hit"
4. Check the box to enable macros
5. Select your macro from the pulldown
6. **Uncheck** "continue execution" if you want to stop.  It is checked by default.

Also, there *are* ways to play an arbitrary wav file, but that seems excessive for an alert.  Perhaps the forced "beep" is the best, since that at least *sounds* different than Ding.

Comment: NOTE: Unfortunately the "Run a macro" checkbox is unavailable on the Express Edition of MSVC++2005 and MSVC++2008.

Comment: I chose Nescio's answer for its simplicity. But, yours is very cool too and will be applicable when I do *not* want alarm on every breakpoint.

Comment: Quick and dirty often wins the day.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for the thorough and robust solution. One thing I'd like to add for others who may try to base your solution for other macros like what I tried to do. It seems like its impossible to create a macro method that accepts a parameter and use it in the "When Hit" option of a breakpoint. I tried to implement it for hours until I figured out it my macro disappears from the list once it expects a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. I never really write macros for VS, so I didn't run into that.  Just a lot for excel. I wonder if it disappears from the list but you can still call it somehow, or if it is really *gone* as far as vs is concerned.

Comment: Why is this method better than just setting a sound in Control Panel?

Comment: @NickG Are you _seriously_ commenting on an answer from 8 years ago?  And the question you ask is addressed in the very first line this answer.   In case you missed it, this lets you trigger a sound only on _certain_ breakpoints, not every one.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a macro that runs in response to a breakpoint firing. In your macro, you could do whatever it takes to make a beeping noise.