# How to enumerate sounds registered for applications?

Tags: c#, windows, audio

I need to get list of sounds registered for applications. For instance I need to play sound for Visual Studio in case build failed. How to do it?

Comment: where do you store sounds? resource? local folder? or in database?

Comment: i don't store, I'm looking for already stored sounds

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean that you want to find out what sound has been set (in Control Panel | Sounds) as the sound for the Visual Studio Build Failed event, and play it.

If that's correct, then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80918/adding-my-own-application-events-in-control-panel-sounds) tells me you need to read the registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default` for the appropriate subkey (set up a sound and then check to see where it has been put), and then use call `PlaySound` (further details in the linked question) to play it.