# How to access the Control Panel->Sound->Communications dialog with c#?

Tags: c#, windows

I am working with a program that will often be used hand in hand with some form of Windows phone call.

The other sounds that take place during the execution of my program will sometimes be muffled because the person using the program will have settings in place in the Sound->Communications dialog that will cause this.

Is there any way to access this dialog programatically and adjust the options for the user without them having to do it?

A Subsequent question; is there some way to provide a white-list of programs to Windows as to which programs to NOT apply these settings to?

I just began investigating this issue, so any input is much appreciated!

Comment: may be this question can give you few pointers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80918/adding-my-own-application-events-in-control-panel-sounds?rq=1

Comment: Thank you for your response and the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly access the registry setting the dialog saves to, in order to change the option.

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Multimedia\Audio\UserDuckingPreference
```

Set the `DWORD` value to 0, 1, 2, or 3, to set the respective value in the dialog (top to bottom).

Comment: This is really looking like the answer!  I've tested it manually (without C#) and it does indeed change this dialog option.  Assuming that you can successfully manipulate this with C# (no reason I can think of you wouldn't be able to), and this sounds awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to modify this kind of options with an application... however, if you also need it to manipulate sounds, [PlaySound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712879.aspx) is the API, and also see [Play System Sounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712868%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your response, as well as the ideas to read about!