# Is it worth investing time in learning Visual Studio Macro System (usage-creation)?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, macros

I have used Visual Studio for a long time, but one feature I have never used is the macro system. I saw a post where someone mentioned he used macros (no elaboration) so I was wondering is it really worth the time investing in learning how to create macros?

If so, what kind of stuff do you make?

There was similar post(s), but I am trying to lean this question more towards: Is it worth learning? I tend to rather know how something works than just using it if it's possible and/or worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Macros are not difficult to learn, and can make your life easier!

For an interesting appllication of macros see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80564/visual-studio-how-to-trigger-an-alarm-when-a-breakpoint-is-hit)

Answer (score 1):

You use macros to make repetitive tasks easier. That is, if you find yourself doing 5 or 6 individual tasks regularly, then it may be worth converting it to a macro, so that you can do it with a single click of the button.

Other things that might be of interest are a switching to a .h file from a .cpp file, if you use C++.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

Although I haven't been using them much - learning VS macros is easy so the "investment" is very little and you get a new tool you can use.