# How do I make WinDbg play a sound when a breakpoint is hit?

Tags: debugging, windbg

Quite a while ago, [someone asked how you can make Visual Studio's debugger play a sound when it hits a breakpoint.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80564/visual-studio-how-to-trigger-an-alarm-when-a-breakpoint-is-hit) For reasons too boring to go into, I often need to instead use the debuggers from the [Debugging Tools for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/), including WinDBG. Hence, this analogous question:

How can I make WinDBG play a sound alert when a breakpoint is hit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use WinDbg's [`.sound_notify`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-sound-notify--use-notification-sound-) command. This command tells WinDbg to play a sound whenever it starts waiting for you to enter a command. A breakpoint being hit is just such a time, so `.sound_notify` should work for your needs.