# Visual Studio BreakPoint Trigger

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, breakpoints

I am working with Visual Studio and just wanted to know if there is any way that I could know that a breakpoint is hit through some notifications.
I work on automation and there are millions of lengths of programe running on multiple systems and we have breakpoints attached on all systems, so is there any way (may be macro ) which can determine me that a breakpoint is hit on a specific machine at this line via some notifications (may be email or something)

I just have an idea, not very sure about it's feasibility though

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Studio: How to trigger an alarm when a breakpoint is hit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80564/visual-studio-how-to-trigger-an-alarm-when-a-breakpoint-is-hit)

This could be what you're looking for, second answer down, example is in VB but should be applicable to C#.